# Stream that computes running median value

Tags: c++, object-oriented, generics, stream, median

I was solving a DSA question, running median in a stream.
And I decided to design my own stream class with additional features.

```
template<typename T>
class ActionInterface{

    public :
        virtual void process(const T element) = 0;
};

template<typename T,typename V>
class Action : public ActionInterface<T> {

    protected :
        
        V result;
        Action() : result((V)false) {};

    public :
        
        virtual void process(const T element) = 0;
        
        virtual V getResult() const final{

            return result;
        };
};

template <typename T>
class Stream{

    private :
        
        vector<T> buffer;
        unordered_map<string, ActionInterface<T>* > actions;

        void processActions(){

            for(const auto& [key, action] : actions){

                action->process(buffer.back());
            }
        }

    public :
        
        Stream(){};

        void addAction(string actionName, ActionInterface<T> *action){

            actions[actionName] = action;            
        }

        void addElement(const T element){

            buffer.push_back(element);
            processActions();
        };

        ActionInterface<T> *getActionObject(string actionName) const{
            
            if(actions.find(actionName) == actions.end())
                return nullptr;
            
            return actions.at(actionName);
        };

        ~Stream(){

             for(const auto& [key, action] : actions){

                delete action;
            }
        }

};

template<typename T,typename V>
class RunningMedian : public Action<T,V>
{
    private :
        priority_queue<T> max_heap;
        priority_queue<T,vector<T>,greater<T>> min_heap;
    
    public :
        RunningMedian() {};
        virtual void process(const T element);
};

template<typename T, typename V> void RunningMedian<T,V>::process(const T element){

    if(element <= this->result)
        max_heap.push(element);
    else
        min_heap.push(element);

    if(abs((int)max_heap.size() - (int)min_heap.size()) > 1){

        if(max_heap.size() > min_heap.size()){

            min_heap.push(max_heap.top());
            max_heap.pop();
        }       
        else{

            max_heap.push(min_heap.top());
            min_heap.pop();
        }
    }

    if(max_heap.size() == min_heap.size())
        this->result = ((V)max_heap.top() + min_heap.top())/2;
    else
        this->result = (max_heap.size() > min_heap.size())? max_heap.top() : min_heap.top();
}

vector<double> Solution::solve(vector<int> &A) {

    int n = A.size();
    Stream<int> *stream = new Stream<int>();
    ActionInterface<int> *action = new RunningMedian<int,double>();
    vector<double> result(n);

    stream->addAction("runningMedian", action);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){

        stream->addElement(A[i]);
        result[i] = ((RunningMedian<int,double> *)action)->getResult()
    }

    delete stream;
    return result;
}
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where are the tests?

---

The code doesn't compile - I needed to add a missing semicolon in `Solution::solve()` and prefix with some definitions:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional>

using std::vector;
using std::string;
using std::unordered_map;
using std::priority_queue;
using std::greater;

namespace Solution 
{
    std::vector<double> solve(std::vector<int>&);
}
```

(Though really I wouldn't have all those `using`s - just write the full names instead).

Even with these fixes, I get a lot of compiler warnings:

```
269757.cpp: In function ‘std::vector<double> Solution::solve(std::vector<int>&)’:
269757.cpp:142:19: warning: conversion from ‘std::vector<int>::size_type’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} to ‘int’ may change value [-Wconversion]
  142 |     int n = A.size();
      |             ~~~~~~^~
269757.cpp: In instantiation of ‘class ActionInterface<int>’:
269757.cpp:35:7:   required from ‘class Action<int, double>’
269757.cpp:102:7:   required from ‘class RunningMedian<int, double>’
269757.cpp:144:66:   required from here
269757.cpp:28:7: warning: ‘class ActionInterface<int>’ has virtual functions and accessible non-virtual destructor [-Wnon-virtual-dtor]
   28 | class ActionInterface{
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
269757.cpp: In instantiation of ‘class Action<int, double>’:
269757.cpp:102:7:   required from ‘class RunningMedian<int, double>’
269757.cpp:144:66:   required from here
269757.cpp:35:7: warning: base class ‘class ActionInterface<int>’ has accessible non-virtual destructor [-Wnon-virtual-dtor]
   35 | class Action : public ActionInterface<T> {
      |       ^~~~~~
269757.cpp:35:7: warning: ‘class Action<int, double>’ has virtual functions and accessible non-virtual destructor [-Wnon-virtual-dtor]
269757.cpp: In instantiation of ‘class RunningMedian<int, double>’:
269757.cpp:144:66:   required from here
269757.cpp:102:7: warning: base class ‘class Action<int, double>’ has accessible non-virtual destructor [-Wnon-virtual-dtor]
  102 | class RunningMedian : public Action<T,V>
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
269757.cpp:102:7: warning: ‘class RunningMedian<int, double>’ has virtual functions and accessible non-virtual destructor [-Wnon-virtual-dtor]
269757.cpp: In instantiation of ‘Stream<T>::Stream() [with T = int]’:
269757.cpp:143:43:   required from here
269757.cpp:70:9: warning: ‘Stream<int>::buffer’ should be initialized in the member initialization list [-Weffc++]
   70 |         Stream(){};
      |         ^~~~~~
269757.cpp:70:9: warning: ‘Stream<int>::actions’ should be initialized in the member initialization list [-Weffc++]
269757.cpp: In instantiation of ‘RunningMedian<T, V>::RunningMedian() [with T = int; V = double]’:
269757.cpp:144:66:   required from here
269757.cpp:109:9: warning: ‘RunningMedian<int, double>::max_heap’ should be initialized in the member initialization list [-Weffc++]
  109 |         RunningMedian() {};
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
269757.cpp:109:9: warning: ‘RunningMedian<int, double>::min_heap’ should be initialized in the member initialization list [-Weffc++]
269757.cpp: In instantiation of ‘Stream<T>::~Stream() [with T = int]’:
269757.cpp:154:12:   required from here
269757.cpp:95:17: warning: deleting object of abstract class type ‘ActionInterface<int>’ which has non-virtual destructor will cause undefined behavior [-Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor]
   95 |                 delete action;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Don't ignore warnings - your compiler is your first reviewer.

For example, that last one causes a memory leak:

```
==2921039== 32 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 2
==2921039==    at 0x4839F2F: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2921039==    by 0x10E515: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:127)
==2921039==    by 0x10D354: allocate (allocator.h:201)
==2921039==    by 0x10D354: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<int> >::allocate(std::allocator<int>&, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:460)
==2921039==    by 0x10C929: std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_allocate(unsigned long) (stl_vector.h:346)
==2921039==    by 0x10C5AF: void std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_realloc_insert<int const&>(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int const&) (vector.tcc:440)
==2921039==    by 0x10BA83: std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::push_back(int const&) (stl_vector.h:1198)
==2921039==    by 0x10F157: std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::greater<int> >::push(int const&) (stl_queue.h:642)
==2921039==    by 0x10EF2B: RunningMedian<int, double>::process(int) (269757.cpp:114)
==2921039==    by 0x10BB1E: Stream<int>::processActions() (269757.cpp:59)
==2921039==    by 0x10B0B7: Stream<int>::addElement(int) (269757.cpp:75)
==2921039==    by 0x10A3F0: Solution::solve(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&) (269757.cpp:140)
==2921039==    by 0x10A58F: main (269757.cpp:153)
==2921039== 
==2921039== 32 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 2
==2921039==    at 0x4839F2F: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2921039==    by 0x10E515: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:127)
==2921039==    by 0x10D354: allocate (allocator.h:201)
==2921039==    by 0x10D354: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<int> >::allocate(std::allocator<int>&, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:460)
==2921039==    by 0x10C929: std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_allocate(unsigned long) (stl_vector.h:346)
==2921039==    by 0x10C5AF: void std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_realloc_insert<int const&>(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int const&) (vector.tcc:440)
==2921039==    by 0x10BA83: std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::push_back(int const&) (stl_vector.h:1198)
==2921039==    by 0x10F105: std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::less<int> >::push(int const&) (stl_queue.h:642)
==2921039==    by 0x10EFE3: RunningMedian<int, double>::process(int) (269757.cpp:121)
==2921039==    by 0x10BB1E: Stream<int>::processActions() (269757.cpp:59)
==2921039==    by 0x10B0B7: Stream<int>::addElement(int) (269757.cpp:75)
==2921039==    by 0x10A3F0: Solution::solve(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&) (269757.cpp:140)
==2921039==    by 0x10A58F: main (269757.cpp:153)
```

---

We don't need a modifiable copy of the input vector, so accept it by reference to const.  Consider accepting arbitrary ranges:

```
std::vector<double> solve(std::ranges::forward_range auto);
```

---

Transferring ownership using raw pointers is error-prone and therefore dangerous.  Use smart pointers instead to indicate the ownership semantics (e.g. pass a unique pointer by value when transferring ownership from one object to another).

Better still, avoid pointers altogether.

---

Consider

```
    using Action<T,V>::result;
```

That lets us write `result` instead of the ugly `this->result` all over the place.

---

Don't write empty default constructors.  Just let the compiler default them naturally.

---

When overriding functions, use the `override` keyword instead of `virtual`.

---

Don't cast `std::size_t` to `int` like this:

> ```
> if(abs((int)max_heap.size() - (int)min_heap.size()) > 1){
>     if(max_heap.size() > min_heap.size()){
> ```

That's probably better split out into simpler tests anyway:

```
if (max_heap.size() > min_heap.size() + 1) {
    min_heap.push(max_heap.top());
    max_heap.pop();
}
if (min_heap.size() > max_heap.size() + 1) {
    max_heap.push(min_heap.top());
    min_heap.pop();
}
```

---

`ActionInterface` and `Action` look like overkill.  Why not just pass a suitable invocable object?  It can hold a reference to a `result` value which it updates.

---

Why does `Stream` have a `buffer` member that is only written and never read?

---

Why do we name the actions, but never use those names for anything?

---

The `for` loop in `solve` looks like it could be a `std::transform()`.

---

## Simplified code

Based on the above observations, I reduced to this version, which gives me no compiler warnings and no memory issues in Valgrind:

```
#include <concepts>
#include <functional>
#include <queue>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

namespace Solution
{
    std::vector<double> solve(const std::vector<int>&);
}


template <typename T>
class Stream
{
    std::vector<std::function<void(T)>> actions = {};

public:
    void addAction(std::invocable<T> auto action)
    {
        actions.emplace_back(std::move(action));
    }

    void addElement(const T value)
    {
        for (const auto& action: actions) {
            action(value);
        }
    }
};

template<typename T>
class RunningMedian
{
    std::priority_queue<T> max_heap = {};
    std::priority_queue<T,std::vector<T>,std::greater<T>> min_heap = {};
    T& median;

public:
    RunningMedian(T& median)
        : median{median}
    {}

    void operator()(const T element)
    {
        if (element < median)
            max_heap.push(element);
        else
            min_heap.push(element);

        if (max_heap.size() > min_heap.size() + 1) {
            min_heap.push(max_heap.top());
            max_heap.pop();
        } else if (min_heap.size() > max_heap.size() + 1) {
            max_heap.push(min_heap.top());
            min_heap.pop();
        }

        median
            = min_heap.size() < max_heap.size() ? max_heap.top()
            : max_heap.size() < min_heap.size() ? min_heap.top()
            : (max_heap.top() + min_heap.top()) / 2;
    }
};

std::vector<double> Solution::solve(const std::vector<int>& input)
{
    Stream<int> stream{};
    double median = 0.0;
    stream.addAction(RunningMedian<double>{median});

    std::vector<double> result;
    result.reserve(input.size());
    for (auto i: input) {
        stream.addElement(i);
        result.push_back(median);
    }

    return result;
}

// Simple test.  TODO: more rigorous testing
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::vector a = { 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 5};
    const char* sep = "";
    for (auto i: Solution::solve(a)) {
        std::cout << sep << i;
        sep = ", ";
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```